# How can I stop html outputting?

Tags: php, html, output

I am writing an anti-ddos php script, and I want to write a custom load page, but the html page of the orginal html page would be rendered. Is there anyway for me to prevent the html showing up while showing up my php load page

```
<?php require "antiddos.php"?>
```

Comment: Maybe look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php

Comment: Preventing DDOS in the PHP layer is futile, it's far too late in the request pipeline. Executing PHP consumes resources. the whole point of preventing DDOS is to prevent server resources being consumed.

Comment: I don't understand the question, there is no way to prevent HTML to show in index.html for example if the first page where user logs in is pure html. If it's .php file then it's easy, use simple if structure.

Comment: Yes, of course. Why not use `die()` to stop the execution?

Answer (score 0):

@Samuel Wang, you can try check that out by one of this examples.
below assume code of antiddos.php and other file from where you include it.

**1. antiddos.php :**

E.g. before your php code or you can keep html inside the file that won't be an issue.

```
 <?php
    
       echo"<p>This is a test html content of antiddos.php</p>";

        function testcall($TextReceiver ){
            return $TextReceiver;
        }
        function MathMultiplication($Prt1,$Prt2){
            return $Prt1*$Prt2;
        }
    ?>
```

**2. testprocess.php :**

You can use the ob_clean(); function next to your include file statement that will discards the contents / html output from the antiddos.php.

```
<?php require_once("antiddos.php");ob_clean();


echo testcall("Hello this is print call from testprocess.php to antiddos.php");
echo "<br>"; 
echo "MathMultiplication= ". MathMultiplication(4,3);    

?>
```

Conclusion by both the files output: First from the antiddos.php and second one from the testprocess.php

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is a great answer, thank you!